# Seagate 10TB drive showing as 1.2TB on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I just bought a 10TB Seagate NAS drive and Ubuntu (and Debian as well) are showing it as 1.2TB. Is there Yet Another Limit that is broken by the 10TB size? I've tried putting a gpt partition table on it, but parted still does not see the proper size. It is not getting picked up correctly in the kernel, so that is probably the root of the issue. So how do I fix the problem?

```
[  154.088570] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST10000V N0004-1ZD101          PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[  154.089768] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  154.090364] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 2353004544 512-byte logical blocks: (1.20 TB/1.10 TiB)
[  154.091486] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  154.091499] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 34 00 00 00
[  154.092608] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  154.104351] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  596.708969]  sdb:
```

Comment: Does BIOS/UEFI show drive with correct size? Do you have AHCI mode on. Is this an internal drive?

Answer (score 2):

You say it's an NAS drive, which implies you either bought something marketed as a complete NAS solution (in which case it's badly broken, and should be returned) or you put a bare drive in some sort of enclosure. If the latter, then the problem is almost certainly that the enclosure has a 32-bit addressing limit. This usually causes disk capacity to "wrap," sort of like the odometer on an old car. In a car with a 5-digit odometer, once you hit 99,999 miles (or kilometers), the odometer "wraps around" and shows a mileage of 0 when the car really has 100,000 miles on it. When the car has a true mileage of 150,000 miles, the odometer reads 50,000, and so on. Something analogous happens on devices with 32-bit limitations, but the wrap point is typically 2 TiB, then again at 4 TiB, 6 TiB, and 8 TiB. What you're seeing is therefore the part of the disk's capacity above 8 TiB. (Note that [TB is not the same as TiB](http://stopabusingsiprefixes.org/stopabusing.html); TB is smaller than TiB, so you're not seeing a full 2 TB, much less 2 TiB, between 8 TiB and 10 TB.)

This sort of problem is extremely common with USB enclosures. You identified the disk as an [NAS device.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) I'm not all that familiar with this type of device, but my understanding is that these are file-level servers; but your output identifies the disk as `/dev/sdb`, which is *not* how I'd expect a true NAS to appear -- unless you've shown the NAS device's kernel output. Thus, I am a little bit confused. You may want to clarify matters by identifying the exact products involved and from where you're getting that kernel output -- on your Ubuntu computer or on the NAS.

In any event, there are several possible solutions:

- **Direct connection** -- You can connect the disk directly to the computer's motherboard, rather than via your external enclosure. It's very rare to have such problems in Linux with disks that connect directly via a SATA port. (Windows users aren't so lucky; there are Windows drivers with 32-bit limits.)
- **Reconfigure the enclosure** -- Some enclosures have switches that can adjust how they treat the disk. These usually enable a "translation" of eight 512-byte sectors into single 4096-byte sectors, thus raising the 2 TiB limit to 16 TiB. This is big enough to handle your 10 TB disk. (You should be aware that this change will invalidate existing partition definitions, though, so do this only if you have not already partitioned the disk and stored data on it.)
- **Change the interface method** -- Some USB enclosures also sport eSATA ports. Using eSATA normally works around the problem.
- **Get a new enclosure** -- If all else fails, you can often fix the problem by buying a new enclosure. If my suspicion that you're using a USB enclosure is correct, you can either get one that does the sector-size translation I've just described to boost the capacity to 16 TiB or you can switch to an enclosure with a different type of interface, like eSATA or a true NAS that partitions the disk itself and communicates over Ethernet using NFS, SMB/CIFS, or some other higher-level protocol.

Comment: A Seagate RED drive is just a disk drive that is optimized for archival use, otherwise there is nothing special about it. They carry the 10TB in three varieties. I bought the RED version because the intended use is in a  very large file server to hold rare archival accesses.  The results I posted are from that hard drive dropped into a BlacX USB external enclosure so I could study the problem with my laptop instead of standing in the server room. The intended use is as one of 24 drives controlled by an ARC1820 SATA/RAID controller board in the backplane of an Enterprise class server.

Comment: The card alone is probably worth a grand and is one of the best around. So the first step I want to succeed in is to prove that the current kernel can recognize this 10TB drive for what it is.

Comment: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822178997&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Hard+Drives-_-N82E16822178997&gclid=CKmQl83_x9MCFQiBswodspQKBA&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Actually I misremembered that model number. The controller is this, the 24 port variety: http://www.areca.com.tw/products/pcie.htm

Comment: If you posted results from the drive plugged into a USB enclosure, whereas the intended use is plugged into a hardware RAID controller, then the results you've shown are useless, for the reasons I outlined. That said, it's entirely possible that the RAID controller could suffer from a similar limitation. I suggest you plug the disk into the RAID controller and see what *it* shows you. If it shows something similar to what you've described, then look for a firmware update for the RAID controller, and if that doesn't help, contact the RAID controller's manufacturer.

Comment: The RAID controller sees the disk and can read its serial number and such, but does nothing when I attempt to set it to PASSTHROUGH. My thought was that it might require a partition table to do a passthrough, which makes little sense, but hey, you have to change things to get data. Which is why I connected it up otherwise. Yes, it is on my list to contact the manufacturer; I am also going to try opening up the server and trying a direct connect to the backplane SATA ports this afternoon. I simply hoped someone here would tell me there was a simple kernel module or update. Thanks for response.